# Passing a variable to register_taxonomy()

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to create multiple taxonomies. As follows.....

```
$taxonomies = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
  //stuff that defines the taxonomy
register_taxonomy( $taxonomy->singular_name, 'book', $tagArgs );
}
```

It appears that WP dislikes regestering the taxonomy with `$taxonomy->singular_name`. Xdebug givies me the following error.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/wpplugin/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 898
```

I've tried several diffent things. Converting the object to an array and feeding that to register_taxonomy(),  I've tride casting $taxonomy->singular_name as a string and a few other random guessees that yeilded the same result. The only thing that works is putting a quoted string in place of  $taxonomy->singular_name which won't fit my needs.

Does any one have any ideas on this??
Thanks
Greg

Full code here.....

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_taxonomies', 0 );function create_book_taxonomies() {
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wlc_custom_taxonomy';
$taxonomies = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
    $enterMeOnce = $taxonomy->singular_name;
    $book = $taxonomy->singular_name;

    if($taxonomy->singular_name != 'singular-name'){ //exclude the default table row
        $resLabels = array(
                'name'               => _x( $enterMeOnce , 'Post Type General Name' ),
                'singular_name'      => _x( $enterMeOnce , 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
                'menu_name'          => __( $enterMeOnce  ),
                'name_admin_bar'     => __( $enterMeOnce  ),
                'all_items'          => __( $enterMeOnce  ),
                'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New ' . $enterMeOnce  ),
                'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit ' . $enterMeOnce  ),
                'new_item'           => __( 'New ' . $enterMeOnce  ),
                'view_item'          => __( 'View ' . $enterMeOnce  ),
                'search_item'        => __( 'Search ' . $enterMeOnce  ),
                'not_found'          => __( 'No '.$enterMeOnce .' found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No '.$enterMeOnce .' found in trash' ),
                'description'         => __( $enterMeOnce .' are special posts that are showcased on the '.$enterMeOnce .' page.' ),
            );
        $resArgs = array(
                'labels' => $resLabels,

                'public'              => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false,
                'publcly_queryable'   => true,
                'show_ui'             => true,
                'show_in_menu'        => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
                'menu_position'       => 5,
                'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-lightbulb',
                'capability_type'     => 'post',
                'meta_box_cb'         => true,
                'show_admin_column'   => true,
                'hierarchical'        => true,
                'has_archive'         => true,
                //'rewrite'           => true,
                /*'capabilities'        => array(
                    'manage_terms' => 'manage_resource',
                    'edit_terms'   => 'manage_categories',
                    'delete_terms' => 'manage_categories',
                    'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts'
                ),*/
                'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'post_format' )
            );

    register_post_type( $book , $resArgs );

        $labels = array(
                'name'                       => _x( $taxonomy->name . ' Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
                'singular_name'              => _x( $taxonomy->name . ' Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
                'menu_name'                  => __( $taxonomy->name . ' Categories', 'text_domain' ),
                'all_items'                  => __( 'All Categories', 'text_domain' ),
                'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Category', 'text_domain' ),
                'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Category:', 'text_domain' ),
                'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Resource Category', 'text_domain' ),
                'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Resource Category', 'text_domain' ),
                'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Category', 'text_domain' ),
                'update_item'                => __( 'Update Category', 'text_domain' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate resource cat names with commas', 'text_domain' ),
                'search_items'               => __( 'Search Resource Categories', 'text_domain' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove resource categories', 'text_domain' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Categories', 'text_domain' ),
                'not_found'                  => __( 'Resource Category Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
                'slug'                       => __( $taxonomy->name . 'category' )
            );

            $args = array(
                'labels'                     => $labels,
                'hierarchical'               => true,
                'public'                     => true,
                'has_archive'                => true,
                'show_ui'                    => true,
                'show_admin_column'          => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
                'show_tagcloud'              => false,
                'rewrite'                    => true,
            );


            register_taxonomy( $taxonomy->singular_name, array( $book ), $args );

            $tagLabels = array(
                'name'                       => _x( 'Writers', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                'singular_name'              => _x( 'Writer', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                'search_items'               => __( 'Search Writers' ),
                'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Writers' ),
                'all_items'                  => __( 'All Writers' ),
                'parent_item'                => null,
                'parent_item_colon'          => null,
                'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Writer' ),
                'update_item'                => __( 'Update Writer' ),
                'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Writer' ),
                'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Writer Name' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate writers with commas' ),
                'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove writers' ),
                'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used writers' ),
                'not_found'                  => __( 'No writers found.' ),
                'menu_name'                  => __( $taxonomy->name . ' Tags' ),
            );

            $tagArgs = array(
                'hierarchical'          => false,
                'labels'                => $tagLabels,
                'show_ui'               => true,
                'show_admin_column'     => true,
                'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
                'query_var'             => true,
                'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'writer' ),
            );

            register_taxonomy( $taxonomy->singular_name, $book, $tagArgs );


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the data type of `singular_name` row in your table and the data type you have in `$taxonomy->singular_name`?

Comment: The data type of the singular_name column is tinytext & var_dump($taxonomy->singular_name) reports it as a string. `public 'singular_name' => string 'Another' (length=7)'

Comment: `var_dump($taxonomy->singular_name)` should be `string(7) "Another" `. Are you sure that you are doing `var_dump($taxonomy->singular_name)`? Can you post your full code?

Comment: Full code posted above. I verified the var_dump and it was correct. i.e. string(7) "Another"

Comment: Why are you registering two taxonomies with the same name for the same object type? I don't think you can do that.

Comment: One is a hierarchical the other is not. The code within the foreach loop come nearly verbatim from the wp codex on regester_taxonomy(). It works fine except for the problem described above. I have a hacky way of fixing it by adding a counter and then replacing $taxonomy->singular_name with 'somestring' . $counter

Comment: So, you have the answer: you can not register two taxonomies with the same name.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the separate taxonomies within the foreach loop register and work fine. The problem arrises when I try to pass the $wpdb object ($taxonomies>singular_name) to register_taxonomy(). That's when things fail.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue here is the foreach statement. I changed the loop from

```
foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
```

to

```
for ($counter=0; $counter < sizeof($taxonomy); $counter++) {
```

as well as all relivant itirators so....

```
register_taxonomy( $taxonomy->singular_name, 'book', $tagArgs );
```

became

```
register_taxonomy( $taxonomy[$counter]->name, $book, $args );
```

and all went  well.

I suspect this is a a problem with the memory of the host machine but I'm not sure if anyone has any insight as to why this worked I'd like to hear it. But for now this problem is solved.